# How many times in the NBA history was the Coach of the year fired?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba, coaching

The Toronto Raptors fired their head coach Dwane Casey on 11 May 2018 after losing to the Cleveland Cavaliers in the second round playoffs of 2017-2018 season. This happened only days after Dwane Casey was voted the NBA coach of the year.

How many times in the NBA history has a head coach been fired on the same year he won the coach of the year award?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the [Coach of The Year award winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Coach_of_the_Year_Award) that [did not come back](http://hoopsanalyst.com/?p=1824) to the team the next season:

- Dwane Casey - Toronto Raptors (17-18)
- George Karl - Denver Nuggets (12-13)
- Pat Riley - Los Angeles Lakers (89-90)
- Dolph Schayes - Philadelphia 76ers(65-66)

Casey, and Schayes were fired by their teams. Pat Riley [resigned](http://articles.latimes.com/1990-06-11/news/mn-267_1_pat-riley), it's believe the Lakers were "kind" enough not to embarrass the coach of the year and let him resign. Goerge Karl's contract was up at the end of the season he won the award and the Nuggets did not re-sign him.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to George Karl in 2013; see [this Yahoo! Sports article](https://sports.yahoo.com/news/nba--sources--nuggets-fire-coach-george-karl-152614807.html).